# why does this Probability Density Function not integrate to 1?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to get to grips with Pearson MCC and am told that this function

$$\frac{e^{\bigg(-0.5\cdot\bigg(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\big(\frac{(1-x^2)}{n-2}\big)}}\bigg)^2\bigg)}}{\sqrt{\bigg(\frac{(1-x^2)}{(n-2)}\bigg)\cdot 2\pi}}$$

describes the said PDF. It certainly plots to look like one [image: PDF plot]

Please note that in the evaluation below, I put a value of $n$.

I would expect the integral between $-1$ and $1$ to evaluate to $1$ but actually I get a little less than $1$ courtesy of Wolfram Alpha [image: Wolfram Alpha integral result]

Since $-1\lt r\lt 1$, these limits look good?

Why do I not get $1$ as the integral?

Comment: Probably because $n$ is finite.

Comment: Hey, @user3733558, you are right. Put that as an answer and I will tick it.

Comment: This is imaginary outside $[-1,1]$, so do not use $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

Comment: @GEdgar, also correct. 1-x^2 does that v nicely.

Comment: So at least I know that the function only approaches a PDF for large n. I put 100 in and go much nearer.

Comment: @nerak99 The usual pdf should integrate to $1$ independent of parameters, provided that the event which it describes happens with certainty.

Comment: I am no statistician and have ended up having to look at some PMCC stuff out of my normal bailiwick, however, this has been helpful. I think that the function in question may illustrate that PMCC is not a pdf in the usual sense of the word but approximates to one for large n. That is a learning for me.

Comment: If I integrate with a large n and appropriate limits, should I get the same values as the critical value tables for PMCC?

Comment: @nerak99 thanks for the offer, but I don't feel that a short hint like that one is actually worth being rewarded. Besides, user is making a good point, and I'm as surprised as you are: a PDF shouldn't behave like that. Out of curiosity, what is the source for this function definition?

Comment: This looks like normal distribution but with an extra parameter n which you can choose according to your needs.

Comment: @Divide1918: $n$ is presumably the sample size leading to $\sqrt{\frac{1-r^2}{n-2}}$ as an estimator of the standard error of the sample correlation and the rest is like a normal approximation, though with an issue that the correlation should be in $[-1,+1]$

Comment: There are other effects too, which in the similar case of the $t$-distribution means that the normalising constant should not be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ but something more complicated

Comment: @user3733558 I am trying to track down where I go the function from

Comment: Here is the source https://www.researchgate.net/post/What-is-the-formula-to-calculate-the-critical-value-of-correlation